# Using Generics as Default Values for Function Properties in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I am trying to extend the SwiftUI View protocol in order to simplify my code. I have created a function on "View" to  set padding, a background, overlay, and shadow rather than having to write all of these modifiers each time throughout my project.

```
@inlinable public func backgroundWithBorder<Background: Shape, S: ShapeStyle>(
                                                _ background: Background,
                                                fill: S,
                                                borderStyle: S,
                                                borderWidth: CGFloat = 2, 
                                                shadow: Bool = false) -> some View {

        self
            .padding()
            .background(background.fill(fill))
            .overlay(background.stroke(borderStyle, lineWidth: borderWidth))
            .shadow(color: shadow ? Color.primary.opacity(0.2) : Color.clear, radius: 20, x: 0, y: 0)

    }
```

The code above works as desired, however I would like to provide default values for the "Background" and "S" generics, such as...

```
@inlinable public func backgroundWithBorder<Background: Shape, S: ShapeStyle>(
                                                    _ background: Background = Circle(),
                                                    fill: S = Color.blue,
                                                    borderStyle: S = Color.green,
                                                    borderWidth: CGFloat = 2, 
                                                    shadow: Bool = false) -> some View
```

Note: I am using generics, because I don't always want the same shape, and I want to use a gradient fill in some instances.

When I add these default values I get the error

> Default argument value of type 'Circle' cannot be converted to type
>   'Background' "Insert ' as! Background'
>
> Default argument value of type 'Color' cannot be converted to type 'S'
>   "Insert ' as! S'

When I do this the errors go away inside the extension

```
@inlinable public func backgroundWithBorder<Background: Shape, S: ShapeStyle>(
                                                _ background: Background = Circle() as! Background,
                                                fill: S = Color.blue as! S,
                                                borderStyle: S = Color.blue as! S,
                                                borderWidth: CGFloat = 2, 
                                                shadow: Bool = false) -> some View {
```

In the ContentView, however, I get the error...

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Text("World")
}
.backgroundWithBorder()
```

> Generic parameter 'Background' could not be inferred
>
> Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred

Again, if I provide values, rather than using the default input parameter, it builds and runs perfectly fine.

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Text("World")
}
.backgroundWithBorder(Circle(),
                      fill: Color.blue,
                      borderStyle: Color.green,
                      shadow: true)
```

In summary, is it possible to provide default values for these generics so I am not writing the same values over and over in my code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a clear contradiction between using generics and having default values. Instead why not create a wrapper function that supplies hardcoded values to the original function

```
@inlinable public func backgroundWithBorder() {
    self.backgroundWithBorder(Circle(), fill: Color.blue, borderStyle: Color.green)
}
```